# Why does storing the value in a variable has an effect to exponentiation operator

Tags: python

Why does it matter if I store the value in a variable to the exponentiation operator (tested in python 3.6)?

```
>>> -7**2
-49
>>> y=-7
>>> y**2
49
```

the first one is clear wrong!

Comment: `-7**2` is equivalent to `-(7**2)`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: when you do y=-7 and y**2, its actually doing (-7)*(-7) which gives +49.

Answer (score 1):

You are a victim of something called *operator precedence*.

In Python, operators are basically functions. However, unlike normal function calls, which always come with a pair of brackets denoting what goes into the function, operators do not. There is therefore a need for [a list of well-defined rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) which affect how expressions including operators are parsed.

For example, if you were to read `1 + 2 * 3` naively, from left to right, you would expect an answer of `9`, instead of the mathematically correct `7`. To achieve the right result, `*` is defined to have a higher *precedence* than `+`. This leads to an implicit pair of parentheses being inserted into the expression, changing it to `1 + (2 * 3)`.

Another way to look at this is to see how the operators are translated Operators with higher precedence *bind to their arguments earlier*. So, going back to the earlier example, `*` binds to `2` and `3` first, so we get `1 + *(2, 3)`. Only then does `+` bind, which gives `+(1, *(2, 3))`.

Returning to your original question: the reason you get a different result is that the exponentiation operator, `**`, has a higher precedence than the unary negation operator, `-`. Therefore, `7 ** 2` is performed first, which gives `49`, which is *then* negated to give `-49`.

Conversely, when you perform `y = -7`, you are evaluating the unary negation first. The next expression is then simply `(-7) ** 2`, which is, of course, `49`.